# Entity units from Jackson's Electrodynamics

Tags: units

From Jackson's equation (14.60) $\frac{d^2 I}{d\omega d\Omega}$ is the *energy radiated per unit solid angle per frequency interval*. From this I deduce that $I$ has energy units, and $\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d^2 I}{d\omega d\Omega} \rightarrow \frac{d^2 I}{d\omega da}$ has units of energy per area per frequency interval.

If you look at expression (15.51a) (he cites equation (14.60) in the same paragraph), $\frac{d I_1}{d\omega}=\frac{c}{2\pi}|\vec{E}\left(\omega\right)|^2$, using previous deduction, it should have units of energy per frequency interval, but Jackson says it has units of energy per area per frequency interval.

If I use the definitions he cites to get equation (15.51a) I'm able to obtain $\frac{1}{b^2}\frac{d^2 I}{d\omega d\Omega}=\frac{c}{2\pi}|\vec{E}\left(\omega\right)|^2$, which makes sense to me. Is his definition of "$I$" of equation (15.51a) different from equation (14.60)? Or I'm missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $A(t)$ and $A(\omega)$ have different units: see equation 14.55. I think that is the standard convention he uses for Fourier transform so you should expect similar unit differences between $f(t)$ and $f(\omega)$ for any function $f$. In addition, equation 15.53 tells us that $\frac{d I}{d \omega} (\omega)$ and $\frac{d I}{d \omega} (\omega,b)$ have different units as well (in fact they differ by units of area). I think if you are careful with this, you'll work it out.